# Referencing closest node_modules from VSCode launch.json settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to set up a debugger that runs a program that resides in the closest parent node_modules folder.

My folder structure is as follows:

- Root

  - node_modules
  - Module A

    - node_modules
    - test

      - A.test.ts
  - Module B

    - node_modules
    - test

      - B.test.ts

When the VSCode editor is working on the A/B.test.ts file, I want to be able to specify in the `launch.json` file that a file from the closest `node_modules` folder should be called (no the one under root).

right now I'm doing something like this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Current Test File",
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "program": "${fileDirname}/../node_modules/vitest/vitest.mjs", // <---
      "args": ["run", "${relativeFile}"],
      "smartStep": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

But this won't work for a file located at `Root/Module A/test/sub folder/C.test.ts`.

Is there any way of selecting the closest `/node_modules/` folder that is a parent of the currently worked on file?